# Django new version 3.1, the settings file have some changes

Tags: python, django, django-settings

On Django new version 3.1, the settings file have some changes, and I came to ask how I have to proceed to set my static files? The way that I usually did doesn't work more.

#### Last versions:

```py
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

#### Version 3.1:

```py
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
```

#### I usually set my static files like this:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

If I insert the `import os` will work, but is it the right practice?
What is the best practice to set this?
Thank you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This change makes it a lot easier for you to define your `STATIC` and `MEDIA` variables. You don't even need to import `os` for this purpose and all you need is to add following codes to your `settings.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent # which shows the root directory of your project

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static' # is equal to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media' # is equal to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent / "static_cdn"
```

try this if you want to add your STATIC_ROOT inside environment directory