# Managing static files in Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-3.1

There are some changes in the Django 3.1 update and settings file has bee changes a bit as `import os` has been dropped. I have created a new project on Django 3.1 and referred to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) for managing static files. I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436120/django-new-version-3-1-the-settings-file-have-some-changes) from StackOverflow but it didn't work out for me.

#### My project structure:

```sh
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── project
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   └── js
│       └── fullscreen_toggle.js
└── templates
```

#### local.py:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '----secretKey----'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','0.0.0.0']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'easynotes.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'easynotes.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

APPEND_SLASH = False

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "live-static", "static-root")

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "live-static", "media-root")
```

#### Console output in inspect element:

```js
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/fullscreen_toggle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 2):

Django 3.1 no longer uses `os` bydefault to join it's paths. It's switched to pathlib instead.

This means you can join your folders like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR / "static",
)

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "live-static"
```

And there should be no need to `import os` in `settings.py` at all now.

See here for the docs on what's new in 3.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/

Comment: I have edited the `local.py` accordingly. `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR / "static",
)

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "live-static" / "static-root"

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "live-static"/ "media-root"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

But it's still showing same error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

first, write this command, 'python manage.py collectstatic' if this didn't solved your problem then add this lines in your project urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I tried command `python manage.py collectstatic` and it copied the static files to `/project/live-static/static-root`. Then, I also tried adding the code given above but it didn't work. Same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this issue however, I've found that the static files are able to load when they are inside of the projects folder, and the STATICFILES_DIRS are defined as follows:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
```

Perhaps there's an issue with how the BASE_DIR is defined it looks at the projects folder as the BASE_DIR though I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code at the end of the settings.py file did the trick

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/home/fabi/proyectos/butler/static/', #the absolute path to your static fil
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To quickly fix this import os at the top of your settings.py file

Another way however, might be to learn more about how pathlib works and update your BASE_DIR, DATABASES, STATICFILES_DIRS, and other files to use the newer, modern approach.
The first way is better if you're new to Django  and works just fine